# Solve $\left\lfloor x - 1/2 \right\rfloor^2 = 25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I would just like to confirm my approach to this equation:
$$\lfloor x - 1/2 \rfloor^2 = 25$$

Now square root both sides
$$\lfloor x - 1/2\rfloor = \pm5.$$

By the definition of floored value we have

$$\lfloor x - 1/2 \rfloor \leqslant x - 1/2 < \lfloor x - 1/2 \rfloor + 1.$$

Now, when the the floor expression is equal to $5$ we find that
\begin{align*}
    5 &\leqslant x - 1/2 < 5+1 \\
    11/2 &\leqslant x < 13/2
\end{align*}
Similarly, if the expression is equal to $-5$ we find that
\begin{align*}
    -5 &\leqslant x - 1/2 < -5 + 1 \\  
    -9/2 &\leqslant x < 7/2  
\end{align*}

Now, can I say that the solution groups are: $[-9/2,-7/2)\cup[11/2,13/2)$?
Or is there something I'm missing, thank you.

Comment: Nothing to add, this is a fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks really solid. Nice work!

Note that I have edited your post to make it more readable: the math is centered and I've corrected your title formatting.